# center input text in a mui TextField

Tags: material-ui

My TextField input wont center. I am using mui TextField to build a form.

Can anyone help, I have been trying a few different things but I can get it to work.

```
  <TextField
        size="small"
        id="username"
        placeholder="Username"
        type="email"
        value={values.username}
        error={touched.username && !!errors.username}
        helperText={touched.username ? errors.username : ''}
        onChange={handleChange('username')}
        onBlur={handleBlur('username')}
        variant="outlined"
        InputProps={{ className: classes.input }}
      />



const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  input: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  inputCenter: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'red',
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `MUI v5` I think for text alignment you can use `sx` prop of mui :

```
<TextField
    InputProps={{
        sx: {
            "& input": {
                textAlign: "center"
            }
        }
    }}
/>
```

reference : [The sx prop](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/)

Or if you are using `MUI v4` try :

```
 inputProps={{
        style: { textAlign: "center" }
      }}
```

Comment: Type '{ sx: { '& input': { textAlign: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<InputProps> | Partial<FilledInputProps> | Partial<OutlinedInputProps>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'sx' does not exist in type 'Partial<InputProps> | Partial<FilledInputProps> | Partial<OutlinedInputProps>'.ts(2322)
TextField.d.ts(158, 3): The expected type comes from property 'InputProps' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextFieldProps'

Comment: When i use sx I get the error I posted above

Comment: are you using v4 components?

Comment: "@material-ui/core": "4.12.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.3.10",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.2.5",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.64",
    "@mui/material": "5.2.8",
    "@mui/styles": "5.2.3",

Comment: These are all the mui ones

Comment: Is that a package I would need to install?

Comment: I have updated the answer try second solution first